# No ZLIB support with Pillow w/ Python3.3

Tags: macos, python-3.x, zlib

I'm having difficulty getting png support into a django project.

I'm in a virtual env with python 3.3.2 and Django 1.5. Everything ran smoothly when on linux, but I've moved over to OSX and am having some trouble getting situated.

I have been using pillow for image support in the project, but on osx when installing pillow I get:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
PIL SETUP SUMMARY
--------------------------------------------------------------------
version      Pillow 2.1.0
platform     darwin 3.3.2 (default, Aug 14 2013, 21:19:39)
             [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
*** ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not available
*** TIFF G3/G4 (experimental) support not available
*** FREETYPE2 support not available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
*** WEBP support not available
```

I only care about the missing zlib. I have no idea how to get this going. Hours of trying various google results didn't help, so here I am. There are no dev packages like on linux, so I installed libpng, libzip via brew but that wasn't right apparently.

Does anyone know how I might tackle this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what worked for me (OSX 10.9, Python 2.7.8):

```
$ brew tap homebrew/dupes
$ brew install zlib
$ brew link --force zlib
```

Then install Pillow:

```
$ pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 1):

Before installing Pillow you should install its dependencies. To fix:

First uninstall Pillow

```
pip uninstall Pillow
```

Then install it's dependencies

```
brew install libtiff libjpeg webp littlecms
```

I already had installed the following, but you can give it a try:

```
brew install libpng zlib
```

Re-install Pillow

```
pip install Pillow
```

Answer (score 1):

This command in your virtualenv should help without tapping `dupes` in homebrew:

`pip install -I --no-cache-dir pillow -v --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I$(xcrun --show-sdk-path)/usr/include"`

It works for me on OS X El Capitan but it should also work on other versions.